# Undefined index: user_role in RegisterController.php

Tags: php, forms, laravel, radio-button, user-input

i want to save the radio button value to users database. but there is a 
ERROR:

> Undefined index: user_role
>      in RegisterController.php

may i know how to solve this error?

migration:

```
 Schema::table('users',function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_role');

    });
```

Register controller:

```
   protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'stuID'=> $data['stuID'],
        'user_role'=>$data['user_role'],
    ]);
}
```

blade file:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ 
      route('register') }}">
                 {{ csrf_field() }}

 <label for="user_role" class="col-md-4 control-label  ">Role</label>

        <div class="user_role" id="user_role" data-toggle="buttons">
             <label class="btn btn-default user_role">
              <input type="radio" name="user_role" id="lecturer" value="1">
                    <span class="radio-dot"></span>
                      <span class="user_role-word">Lecturer</span>
             </label>

             <label class="btn btn-default user_role">
                <input type="radio" name="user_role" id="student"value="2">
                   <span class="radio-dot"></span>
                     <span class="user_role-word">Student</span>
              </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Debug your code within the function ---> `dd($data);` (write this before the return statement)

Comment: this is the output "_token" => "iVFFu4Gh7ugewqZLdsDbxeKgs3EpXNG2mTPP0Qmi"
  "options" => "1"
  "name" => "ss"
  "stuID" => "sn098211"
  "email" => "kavi.tha31@yahoo.com"
  "password" => "123456"
  "password_confirmation" => "123456"

Comment: "user_role" is not included in your data.. is it inside <form>? Did you select a value for user_role when your submitted the form?

Comment: you are not getting value of `user_role` in your output. you might have not selected any option when you submit form. solution is that checked by default one option

Comment: Please post your entire form HTML code. Looks like your POST data is not getting the user role.

Comment: @parpar it is inside the form. and i selected the option before i submit.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator please check my edited post(blade file). i already selected the option before i submit and the default value in database is 0 . do i need to set the default value to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't select one of your radio buttons when submitting the form, you won't have `$data['user_role']` index in the array. You can prevent this error by making radio buttons required in the form OR check the array for `user_role` index before use.

```
return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'stuID'=> $data['stuID'],
        'user_role'=> isset($data['user_role']) ? $data['user_role'] : null
    ]);
```

Comment: i tried your code. it showed an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_role' cannot be null

Comment: Make `user_role ` Nullable.